# F.E.A.R 2 freezing issues when on loading screen

Tags: technical-issues, ps3, fear-2-project-origin

I'm having a problem with my FEAR 2 copy on my PS3, the game works just fine, I'm just past chapter 9/10 where I'm looking for Keegan, anyway, when the game is loading on the loading screen, no matter how long I wait, it always freeze on 84% loaded.

Now there's one problem, I cannot find any game data to delete, except game saves which I'm not risking to delete when it probably has no relevance to the freezing issues.

I checked the disc of my copy, it doesn't seem to be scratched or anything so this isn't the victim.

When the game freezes on the loading screen, I cannot access to the PS screen (when pressing the PS button on the controller), so I'm risking to turn it off, when it's turning off, I hear 3 beeps and it's still on... no matter how long I wait, it still won't turn off.

How can I fix this issue?

EDIT: I got the copy of FEAR 2 from [LOVEFiLM](http://www.lovefilm.com).